# How to select an element with a parent that has a following parent with a specific element? (:has)

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

I am trying to select an element ".cell-rich". Which has a ".parent", but only when it's before another ".parent" which has an element ".cell-featured". I was hoping this would work, but it doesn't. Does anyone know if this is even possible with CSS without adding any additional classname to the parent container?

```
.parent:has(.cell-rich) + .parent:has(.cell-featured) > .cell-rich {
  padding-bottom: 0;
}
```

Example HTML:

```
<div class="parent">
  <div class="cell-rich"></div>
</div>
<div class="parent">
  <div class="cell-rich"></div>
</div>
<div class="parent">
  <div class="cell-featured"></div>
</div>
<div class="parent">
  <div class="cell-rich"></div>
</div>
```

So based on this example i only wish to set `padding-bottom: 0;` to the 2nd parent's ".cell-rich" element.

EDIT:

As i was messing around and checking with browser dev tools i noticed that using:

```
.parent:has(.cell-rich) + .parent:has(.cell-featured)
  padding-bottom: 0;
}
```

-- actually applies the property to the `.parent:has(.cell-featured)` and not `.parent:has(.cell-rich)`.

Comment: Please add enought details incl your HTML markup. Also state which elements you want to select on which condition.

Comment: I literally state it in the first sentence 'I am trying to select an element ".cell-rich"'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no way to select previous siblings e.g. `.parent.cell-rich` in CSS. With +,~ operators you can only select next sibling/s. If you don't want to add extra classnames, you can try using JS to achieve that.

Comment: Thanks, for the reply, using `~ operator` did not do it. As i'm messing around and checking 'inspect' to see where it applies this property, i noticed that actually `.parent:has(.cell-featured)` is being selected here and not the `.parent:has(.cell-rich)`. Which kind of changes my question a bit. I'll update the post.